# How to edit cells with backgrid

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

I am trying an example with backgrid paging. I have to edit a cell content on click of edit button then save the updated cell content to the server. Here iam rendering the buttons using backgrid cell extention but not able to figure it out how to enable a cell for editing on click of the button.

Here is the sample am trying.. In EditCell i have a method editRow in which i have to perform the updation.

Thanks

```
(function(){
//Namespacing the views collections and models
window.App = {
Models: {},
Views: {},
Collections: {},
Helpers: {}
},
//Template helper to load the template of any id    
App.Helpers.template = function(id){
return _.template($('#' + id).html());
}


//Person Model
App.Models.Person = Backbone.Model.extend({});

//Person collection - People
App.Collections.People = Backbone.PageableCollection.extend({
model: App.Models.Person,
state: {
pageSize: 10
},
mode: "client"
});


var personCollection = new App.Collections.People([
{
id: 1,
name: 'Trim',
age: 33,
occupation: 'Dotnet Programmer'
},
{
id: 2,
name: 'Crum',
age: 25,
occupation: 'Developer'
},
{
id: 3,
name: 'Drum',
age: 46,
occupation: 'Designer'
},
{
id: 4,
name: 'Srum',
age: 27,
occupation: 'Java Programmer'
},
{
id: 5,
name: 'Vrum',
age: 24,
occupation: 'Developer'
},
{
id: 6,
name: 'Brum',
age: 29,
occupation: 'Designer'
},
{
id: 7,
name: 'Frum',
age: 33,
occupation: 'Dotnet Programmer'
},
{
id: 8,
name: 'Jrum',
age: 25,
occupation: 'Developer'
},
{
id: 9,
name: 'Lrum',
age: 46,
occupation: 'Designer'
},
{
id: 10,
name: 'Hrum',
age: 27,
occupation: 'Java Programmer'
},
{
id: 11,
name: 'Prum',
age: 24,
occupation: 'Developer'
},
{
id: 12,
name: 'Zrum',
age: 29,
occupation: 'Designer'
}
]
);

var EditCell = Backgrid.Cell.extend({
template: _.template('<button>Edit</button>'),
events: {
"click": "editRow"
},
editRow: function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
//Enable the occupation cell for editing 
//Save the changes 
//Render the changes.
},
render: function () {
this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
this.delegateEvents();
return this;
}
});

var columns = [{
name: "id",
label: "ID",
editable: false,
cell: Backgrid.IntegerCell.extend({
orderSeparator: ''
})
}, {
name: "name",
label: "Name",
cell: "string"
}, {
name: "age",
label: "Age",
cell: "integer"
}, {
name: "occupation",
label: "Occupation",
cell: "string" 
}, {
name: "actions",
label: "Actions",
cell: EditCell 
}];

// Initialize a new Grid instance
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
columns: columns,
collection: personCollection
});

var paginator = new Backgrid.Extension.Paginator({
collection: personCollection
});

// Render the grid and attach the root to your HTML document
$("#grid").append(grid.render().el);
$("#paginator").append(paginator.render().$el);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code solved my problem.. With the below code we can make each cell editable/noneditable depending upon a condition. Still looking for a better approach to Enable editing on edit button click.

```
(function(){
//Person Model
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

//Person collection - People
var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Person
});


var personCollection = new People([
{
id: 1,
name: 'Trim',
age: 33,
occupation: 'Dotnet Programmer'
},
{
id: 2,
name: 'Crum',
age: 25,
occupation: 'Developer'
},
{
id: 3,
name: 'Drum',
age: 46,
occupation: 'Designer'
},
{
id: 4,
name: 'Srum',
age: 27,
occupation: 'Java Programmer'
},
{
id: 5,
name: 'Vrum',
age: 24,
occupation: 'Developer'
},
{
id: 6,
name: 'Brum',
age: 29,
occupation: 'Designer'
},
{
id: 7,
name: 'Frum',
age: 33,
occupation: 'Dotnet Programmer'
},
{
id: 8,
name: 'Jrum',
age: 25,
occupation: ''
},
{
id: 9,
name: 'Lrum',
age: 46,
occupation: ''
},
{
id: 10,
name: 'Hrum',
age: 27,
occupation: 'Java Programmer'
},
{
id: 11,
name: 'Prum',
age: 24,
occupation: 'Developer'
},
{
id: 12,
name: 'Zrum',
age: 29,
occupation: 'Designer'
}
]
);

var MyCell = Backgrid.Cell.extend({
initialize: function (options) {
MyCell.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
this.listenTo(this.model, "backgrid:edited", this.doSomething);
},
doSomething: function () {
console.log('something');
},
enterEditMode: function () {
this.$el.width((this.$el.outerWidth() - 10) + 'px');
Backgrid.Cell.prototype.enterEditMode.apply(this, arguments);
},
exitEditMode: function () {
this.$el.width(false);
Backgrid.Cell.prototype.exitEditMode.apply(this, arguments);
}
});

var columns = [{
name: "id", // The key of the model attribute
label: "ID", // The name to display in the header
editable: false, // By default every cell in a column is editable, but *ID* shouldn't be
// Defines a cell type, and ID is displayed as an integer without the ',' separating 1000s.
cell: "string", //Backgrid.IntegerCell.extend({ tagName: "td style='text-align:left'" })
editable:false,
isEnabled: false
}, {
name: "name",
label: "Name",
// The cell type can be a reference of a Backgrid.Cell subclass, any Backgrid.Cell subclass instances like *id* above, or a string
cell: "string", // This is converted to "StringCell" and a corresponding class in the Backgrid package namespace is looked up
editable:false
}, {
name: "age",
label: "Age",
cell: "string", // An integer cell is a number cell that displays humanized integers
editable: false
}, {
name: "occupation",
label: "Occupation",
cell: MyCell, // A cell type for floating point value, defaults to have a precision 2 decimal numbers
editable: function (c, m) {
if (typeof(c.collection) === 'undefined')
return false;
else
return (c.attributes.age <= 30) ? true : false;
}
}];

// Initialize a new Grid instance
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
columns: columns,
collection: personCollection
});


// Initialize a client-side filter to filter on the client
// mode pageable collection's cache.
var filter = new Backgrid.Extension.ClientSideFilter({
collection: personCollection,
fields: ['name']
});

// Render the grid and attach the root to your HTML document
$("#grid").append(grid.render().el);
$("#grid").before(filter.render().el);

})();
```